# Problemas con traer un dato tipo foto desde un api

Tags: javascript, datatables

Tengo un api que me devuelve data en la cual lleno en el detatables, en estos precisos momentos tengo problemas con jalar una data que me trae foto de un modelo.

A continuacion dejo el api:

```
for anuncio in anuncios:
            data = {}
            data['id'] = anuncio['id'],
            data['manifestado'] = anuncio['numero_de_manifiesto'],
            data['nave'] = anuncio['nave__nombre'],
            data['tipo_nave'] = anuncio['tipo_nave__descripcion'],
            data['nombre_linea'] = anuncio['linea_naviera__nombre'],
            data['nro_viaje'] = anuncio['nro_viaje'],
            data['agente_maritimo'] = anuncio['agente_maritimo__nombre'],
            data['eslora'] = anuncio['nave__eslora'],
            data['eta'] = anuncio['eta'],
            data['etb'] = anuncio['etb'],
            data['etc'] = anuncio['etc'],
            data['etd'] = anuncio['etd'],
            data['carga'] = anuncio['carga'].upper()
            data['proyecto_articulo'] = anuncio['proyecto_articulo__nombre']
            # data['amarradero'] = anuncio['amarradero__nombre']
            data['reporte_servicio_url'] = reverse('reporte_servicio', kwargs={"pk": anuncio['id']})
            data['atraque_url'] = reverse('acta_maniobra_imprimir', kwargs={"pk": atra[anuncio['id']]}) if anuncio['id'] in atra else None
            data['desatraque_url'] = reverse('acta_maniobra_imprimir', kwargs={"pk": desa[anuncio['id']]}) if anuncio['id'] in desa else None
            data['foto'] = anuncio['tipo_nave__foto'],

            resultado.append(data)
```

También dejo el html donde llamo la data:

```
columns: [
                {
                    data: "foto",
                },
                {data: "manifestado"},
                {data: "nave"},
                {data: "tipo_nave"},
                {data: "nombre_linea"},
                {data: "nro_viaje"},
                {data: "agente_maritimo"},
                {data: "eslora"},
                {data: "eta"},
                {data: "etb"},
                {data: "etc"},
                {data: "etd"},
                {data: "carga"},
                {data: "proyecto_articulo"},
                {
                    "targets": -1,
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": "<i class=\"fa fa-eye\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>",
                    "className": 'anuncio'
                },
                {
                    "targets": -1,
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": "<i class=\"fa fa-eye\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>",
                    "className": 'atraque'
                },
                {
                    "targets": -1,
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": "<i class=\"fa fa-eye\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>",
                    "className": 'desatraque'
                }
            ],
```

El problema es que me trae la url y estaba intentando con el render y defaultContent, pero no se como hacerlo.

Sería de mucha ayuda su aporte, dejo foto del resultado.
Gracias de antemano.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías agregar una columna mas y aplicar un render para poder insertar la imagen de la siguiente manera:

```
columnDefs: [{
  targets: 0,
  render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
    return '<img src="'+data+'">';
  }
}]
```

donde targets especifica la posición de la columna donde quieres que se renderise el código html, y data es el valor que recibes, en tu caso la url de tu imagen.

Comment: Gracias compañero, me sirvio de mucho !

Comment: si te sirvió no olvides seleccionar la respuesta  como correcta!! ayuda de mucho a las demás personas que tengan un problema similar gracias!